# implementing the CTRL-F (find) functionality in swing

Tags: java, swing

I am creating an open source document editor in Java Swing and I want to implement the CTRL-F (find) functionality in swing. Without starting from the ground up is there any open source Java code available which I can borrow where this functionality is already implemented?

Comment: SO isn't about getting points, it's about providing quality content :)

Comment: Perfectly said ....that is one of the reasons I keep my quality bar for acceptance a little high! My grading is very strict :-)

Comment: Note that for a good answer typically a good question is required as well. A -1 for this question as this does not meet my rather low quality bar for questions. See for example the comment of @aaamos on what you can improve to this question

Comment: I am sorry! @aaamos has not given any constructive comment. He has just given out an angry rant. I don't find any constructive comment or suggestion in his comment. It just seems like an outburst.

Comment: I apologise if that came across as an "angry rant" - it certainly wasn't, but perhaps I could have phrased my question a bit more gently. I am glad to see you've edited out that screenshot (which contributed nothing to your question); however, I'm also a bit disappointed that you a) still haven't answered my question b) reacted to what most seem to think is valid criticism of your question with what I take to be a glib comment about the quality of the answers. My intent in stating this is not to offend you but to help teach you about how SO is supposed to work.

Answer (score 4):

**Key Bindings** is what you are looking for. Here is the tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html

**JDialog** (or frame.showInputDialog) is what you should use after the ctrl+F action is fired. Enter the search string here and search the document from the returned string. Again the tutorial is in the java docs.

Highlighting is quite complicated and depends on what code you have written. You will have to use the repaint method on some selected text after using the seBackgroundColor(Color color)

You haven't placed any code so I can't answer with any code. But its a much better idea to see the tutorial and understand it yourself rather than copy-pasting code.

Comment: I am trying to get the complete code for the ctrl+f functionality. Which means that the code should - i) show user a dialog prompting for a string to search ii) find the string in the editor's document model iii) highlight the views which are representing the string using some color.